# Using checkbox in a Listview that implements a cursor from a database

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a listview and i want it to do two different functions. The first one is working, it is when you select something from the list it starts another activity, i do this on the onListItemClick() method. The second one is the one that i am having problems with. I have a checkbox on every member of the list and i want to be able to select multiple elements and do something with the selected members, anything!!!!! because in my code it doesnt work. For the moment i was trying to implement in the OnItemClickListener() method but it didnt go well

here is my java code with the listview:

```
public class Lista_general extends ListActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.lista_general);

ListView list = getListView();

final Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

// open database
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(getBaseContext());
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

//necessary for the simple cursor adapter
String columns[] = new String[] { "_id", "nombre", "categoria" };

// cursor whith the query of the database
Cursor c = db.query("PRODUCTO ORDER BY categoria ", columns, null,null, null, null, null);

//necessary for the simple cursor adapter
c.moveToFirst();
String from[] = new String[] { "nombre", "categoria", };
int to[] = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.cate, };


SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.productos, c, from, to,SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

setListAdapter(adapter);

// close database
db.close();

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//  I think here is where i can implement the use of the checkboxes

}
});

}



@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {


Intent i = new Intent(Lista_general.this, Agregar_articulo.class);
i.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(arg3));
i.putExtra("num", "y");
startActivity(i);
}

public void lanzar(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent(Lista_general.this, Agregar_articulo.class);
i.putExtra("num", "n");
startActivity(i);
}
}
```

here is my layout with the listview: lista_general.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/eliminar"
        android:onClick="eliminar" 
        android:enabled="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="lanzar"
        android:text="@string/agregar_art" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:cacheColorHint="@null"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for every row: productos.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"  >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/cate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
     android:id="@+id/name" 
     />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text=""
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"  
    android:clickable="true"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an image of my application. My goal is that when you select different elements with the checkbox the button that is called Eliminar appears and then you can eliminate them.

http://i39.tinypic.com/1z6z0y0.png

Comment: What isn't working currently? The multiple selection? Show the button ?

Comment: I had the same issue, and I solved it by using `setOnItemLongClick`. so when the user has a long click in an item, it will be checked. if you liked the idea I can share some code.

Comment: it would be great if you can show me how you implement the setOnItemLongClick() @Coderji

Comment: The problem is that when I check the checkbox it doesn´t do anything, I want to be able to select multiple checkboxes in the list and for example eliminate them. I tried to write code on the onItemClick() method but it didn´t work, I discovered certain peculiarities, for example: I have to set in the layout of the checkbox android:clickable="False" for it to let me do something, but i want it to be clickable. @Kyu_